# Turn javascript dictionary into JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I have a javascript dictionary:

```
{
  "a": {
      "b": {
          "c": null,
          "d": null
           }
       }
}
```

How can I turn it into a JSON object which I can specify the name and children property? Is there any elegant way to do it? 
The JSON object could be:

```
{
    name:"a"
    children: [{
      name:"b",
      children: [{
          name:"c",
          children: null
           },{
          name:"d",
          children: null}]
       }]
  }
```

Comment: You will need to write a recursive function.

Comment: I'm not sure it was intentional, but this is the first time I've ever seen "JSON Object" written in a post that didn't make me flare up with the need to get all pedantic about JSON strings vs JavaScript objects. Bravo.

Comment: That said, your "JSON Object" isn't valid JSON; the keys need to be in double quotes as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, change the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You need a recursive function, which calls itself for children. Note that in your example, there is only one top-level child (a). I instead use the assumption that the top-level 'name' refers to the name of the actual object itself. If you want to get results exactly like you demonstrate, from an object called 'obj', run toJSON(obj).children[0]. For the overall function, try something like the following:

```
function toJSON(obj, name) {
    var subTree = {
        name: name,
        children: []
    };
    if (obj !== null && Object.keys(obj).length >= 1) {
        for (var child in obj) {
            subTree.children.push(toJSON(obj[child], child));
        }
    } else {
        subTree.children = null;
    }
    return subTree;
}
```

Results of toJSON(obj).children[0]:

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "children": [{
        "name": "b",
        "children": [{
            "name": "c",
            "children": null
        },{
            "name": "d",
            "children": null
        }]
    }]
}
```

Results of toJSON(obj, 'obj'):

```
{
    "name": "obj",
    "children": [{
        "name": "a",
        "children": [{
            "name": "b",
            "children": [{
                "name": "c",
                "children":null
            },
            {
                "name": "d",
                "children": null
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here's a line-by-line explanation:

1. Declares the function, which expects two arguments: the object, and it's name. If you're going to be using toJSON(obj).children[0], though, don't bother with the second argument. It won't affect the result.
2. Declares the result, an object containing information about the current level and all levels below in the object. If you consider the object a tree, this result contains information about the current branch, and all it's branches.
3. Declares the property 'name', containing the name/key of the object at the current level. When you call the function, you need to include the name as second argument because there is no way of dynamically finding the name of a variable. They're passed into functions by value. As described above, though, if you're looking for results EXACTLY like those in your example, you're going to use toJSON(obj).children[0], instead of toJSON(obj, 'obj'), and then don't need to bother with the second argument.
4. Declares the children array, to be filled below
5. Terminates the declaration begun on Line 2
6. Checks if the object ISN'T null, and that it has children, using a handy method of the [Object built-in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), running Lines 7, 8 and 9 if so
7. Iterates over the children of the object, running Line 8 for each child
8. Recursively runs the toJSON() function for each child, to get it's subTree. Because the children can't dynamically figure out their own names, it passes those in as well.
9. Terminates the for loop begun at Line 7
10. If there are no children, run Line 11. This is only run if Lines 7, 8 and 9 are not.
11. Sets children to null (only run if there are no children, as checked by Line 6)
12. Terminates the else started at line 10
13. Returns the current subTree, either to the function if called recursively by the function, or to you if you called it yourself
14. Terminates the function

### Information about the Previous Version, Pre-edit

The original function only used one argument, whereas that above has another argument for 'name'. This is because the original tried to figure out the name of each level within that same level, which I have since realized isn't possible in Javascript. Basically, the original didn't work, and an extra argument had to be added to make it work. For records' sake, though, here was the original function:

```
// THIS FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK. IT'S HERE ONLY FOR HISTORICAL ACCURACY:
function toJSON(obj) {
    var subTree = {
        name: obj.constructor.name,       // This should get the object key
        children: []
    };
    if (Object.keys(obj).length >= 1) {   // If there is at least one child
        for (var child in obj) {
            subTree.children.push(toJSON(obj[child]));
        }
    } else {
        subTree.children = null;
    }
    return subTree;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a recursive function for generating your output:

```
var x = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": null,
            "d": null
        }
    }
};

function generate(item, key) {
    var result = {
        name: key,
        children: []
    };

    for (var _ in item)
        result.children.push(generate(item[_], _))

    if (result.children.length == 0)
        result.children = null;

    return (key == undefined) ? result.children : result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(generate(x), null, 1));
```

Output:

```
[
 {
  "name": "a",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "b",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "c",
      "children": null
     },
     {
      "name": "d",
      "children": null
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

The above `generate` function returns a list instead of a dictionary, because it's possible to have more than one name at the root level. But if we are sure that we have only one name at the root name, we can generate the json like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(generate(x)[0], null, 1));
```

Comment: This is really close, hence the upvote, but your JSON is slightly different from the target, your output at the root should be `{...}` instead of `[{...}]`

Comment: Yes but what happens if the OP has two names in the root level? I took the initiative of returning a list. But it's always possible to extract the first element of my output.

Comment: That's a good initiative, thank you for the clarification. I think it's important to add that to your answer because without that clarification (though, being in the comments likely suffices), there a difference between what was desired and what was delivered. However, you are correct for adding it, I hand't thought it all the way through, my apologies!

Comment: No apologies. You are right that I should have justified it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. It's similar to JuniorCompressor's.

```
function generate(obj) {
  // Return primitives as-is
  if (!(obj instanceof Object)) return obj;

  // Loop through object properties and generate array
  var result = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    result.push({
      name:     key,
      children: generate(obj[key])
    });
  }

  // Return resulting array
  return result;
}
```

As mentioned, the resulting object will actually be an array (in case there is more than one root-level property in the original object). If you really need the resulting object to be an object with only properties name and value, then you should access the first element of the resulting array, like this:

```
generate(obj)[0]
```

Comment: Nice error handling, obviously the rest of us didn't think to handle unusual inputs